# Can you use System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread as a key in a dictionary

Tags: c#, thread-safety, weak-references

I'm currently trying to implement a minimalistic ThreadLocal class. I know this is implemented in DotNet 4, but I'm in a situation where its not possible to upgrade.

My idea is to use a very simple class that holds a weak hashtable and just stores objects based on the current thread as key. (We have a custom implementation of a weak hashtable)

Do you think this is a viable approach or are there any threading issues to consider? 
Is it ok to use current thread as a key, memory issues etc?

```
public class SimpleThreadLocal<T>
{
    private readonly WeakHashtable _threadToValue;

    public SimpleThreadLocal()
    {
        _threadToValue = new WeakHashtable();
    }

    public void Set(T value)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            _threadToValue[Thread.CurrentThread] = value;
        }
    }

    public T Get()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            return (T) _threadToValue[Thread.CurrentThread];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [`LogicalCallContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.logicalcallcontext.setdata.aspx)? Not only that it acts like a TLS, it is actually smarter and will keep your 'TLS' slot value in async callbacks and the like. See [Logical Call Context: Flowing Data across Threads, AppDomains, and Processes](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jeffreyr/archive/2010/09/27/logical-call-context-flowing-data-across-threads-appdomains-and-processes.aspx) and [ExecutionContext vs SynchronizationContext](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx).